# Database query with relationships in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor, relationships

suppose I have the following tables

```
sqlite> SELECT * FROM Artists;
ArtistID|ArtistName
1       |Peter Gabriel
2       |Bruce Hornsby
3       |Lyle Lovett
4       |Beach Boys
5       |Supernatural

sqlite> SELECT * FROM CDs;
CDID|ArtistID|Title              |Date
1   |1       |So                 |1984
2   |1       |Us                 |1992
3   |2       |The Way It Is      |1986
4   |2       |Scenes from the Southside|1990
5   |1       |Security           |1990
6   |3       |Joshua Judges Ruth |1992
7   |4       |Pet Sounds         |1966
```

I want to make this kind of query

```
sqlite>SELECT ArtistID as _id, ArtistName, Title FROM Artists, CDs WHERE Artists.ArtistID=CDs.ArtistID;
```

How can I use that using the Android `SQLiteQueryBuilder` class, what do I need to put for my projectionMap?

Or would it be easier just using the `SQLiteDataBase` class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out. Still had to hardcode the where statement.

```
projectionMap.put(ArtistID, ArtistID + " AS " + _ID);
projectionMap.put(Title, Title);
queryBuilder.setProjectionMap(projectionMap);
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I use that using the Android SQLiteQueryBuilder class

Well, I'd just use `rawQuery()` on `SQLiteDatabase` for that, since you know SQL and have the SQL.

If somebody held a gun to your head to force you to use `SQLiteQueryBuilder`, your projection map is probably mapping `ArtistName` to `ArtistName` or `Artists.ArtistName` and `Title` to `Title` or `CDs.Title`. I have not used `SQLiteQueryBuilder` with an implicit (or explicit) `JOIN`, in part because I only use `SQLiteQueryBuilder` when I write a content provider.

Comment: mapping `ArtistName` to `ArtistName` throws an sqlexception saying there is an ambiguous column.  You may be right a rawQuery() could be what I need here.

Comment: I've updated my questions, the original query was not working because of the _id I left out of my example.  I am needing the _id to get adapters, etc to work.  Do you know how to do that projection?

Comment: @schwiz: I still say you are better served using `rawQuery()`. Otherwise, map `_ID` to `Artists._ID`, I guess.